# getting no active transcation exception while using sessionFactory.openSession() but not with sessionfactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are migrating from hibernate 3.2 to hibernate 5. In our application we need to have the hibernate session active for multiple transactions, hence we had to create our implementation of transaction and session handling (@WithinTransaction, @WithinSession aspects using AspectJ library).

Session factory configuration:

```
<bean id="coreSessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="coreDataSource" />
</property>
<!-- this also works if mapping files are in a jar-File -->
<property name="mappingLocations">
  <list>
    <!-- takes all mapping files located in that directory including subdirectories -->
    <value>classpath:com/ubitronix/uiem/persistence/mapping/*.hbm.xml
    </value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class"> ${hibernate.cache.provider_class} </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop >
  </props>
</property>
<property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor"></property>
```

Code for creating session:

```
public static Session startLongSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    logger.trace("Opening long session with sessionFactory " + sessionFactory);
    Session session = null;
    
    Object o = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(sessionFactory);
    if (o != null){
        if (o instanceof SessionHolder){
            logger.warn("Session already bound to thread");
            SessionHolder holder = (SessionHolder) o;
            session = holder.getSession();
            
            if (!session.isOpen()){
                logger.warn("... and session is already open");
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexcpected Exception");
            }           
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexcpected Exception");
        }
    } else {    
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
          session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          try {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
          } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Could not bind session ... trying to release it");
            session.disconnect();
          }
        }
    }
    return session;
  }
```

Code for handling the transaction and calling the proxy:

```
public Object callback(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
      Object result;
      //HibernateSession is our utility calss for getting sessions
      Session session = HibernateSession.getInstance().getCurrentSession(database);
      session=HibernateSession.getInstance().getCurrentSession(database);
      boolean txOpened = false;
      Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
      if (!(tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)) {
        logger.trace("Opening transaction for " + DatabaseAspect.joinPointToString(pjp));
        tx.begin();
        //To keep track of whcih call actuall started the transcation
        txOpened = true;
      }
      try {
        logger.trace("Do within Transaction " + pjp.getSourceLocation());
        //Failing while calling the proxy. The transaction is active here but not active inside the method call.
        result = innerCallback.callback(pjp);
        logger.trace("No Error within transaction " + pjp.getSourceLocation());
        if (txOpened && (tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)) {
          logger.trace("Committing transaction for " + DatabaseAspect.joinPointToString(pjp));
          tx.commit();
          txOpened = false;
        }

      } catch (Throwable t) {
        if (txOpened && (tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)) {
          logger.trace("Rolling back transaction for " + DatabaseAspect.joinPointToString(pjp));
          tx.rollback();
          txOpened = false;
        }
        throw t;
      }

      logger.trace("Done within transaction " + pjp.getSourceLocation());

      return result;
    }
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(HibernateTemplate.java:1286)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ubitronix.uiem.persistence.dao.hibernate.HibernateBOFactory$2.doInHibernate(HibernateBOFactory.java:354)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:361)
    ... 25 more
```

What was strange is if I use `session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` the transaction is active and i can execute the query. The problem with this is the session scope. It is open for a single transaction.
I am wondering what changed with `openSession` that the transaction is not being bound to the session.
when I checked the implementation of these methods there is some additional code in `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` for checking for proxies. Do I have to add some logic to bind the transaction to the session?

I am really sorry if the question is not clear, I tried my best to add as many details as possible without making the question too big. Would be happy to provide any additional explanation if required.

Comment: You are working around aproblem you introduced yourself. Remove the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` config property as that actually breaks proper integration with Spring and Hibernate. With that you can ditch your own aspects and all other things and Spring will manage the proper session creation and caching. Another thing is you shouldn't be using `HibernateTemplate` anymore that has been deprecated (sort of) since Hibernate 3.0.1 introduced contextual sessions.

Comment: yes, I agree with the comment but this transaction handling logic is in pretty much all of our projects and this involves a lot of efforts to change to spring based transaction and session handling. and also testing the whole thing again. So they don't want to do it now.

Comment: The main issue is really your code, you are using Spring and then try very hard to work around Spring in your usage of Hibernate. Also `openSession` doesn't create a transaction it opens a session (that is what the method does and doesn't return a thread bound one as `getCurrentSession` is doing). But as stated you can remove all this IF you properly configure things with Spring and use the right method in usage.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Removing the ```hibernate.current_session_context_class``` with open session worked for now. For using spring annotations for transaction handling, don't know when the resources would be allocated. It would be a huge task to edit almost all the applications and test them again. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Or you just hook your own aspects into Spring or annotation those `@WIth*` annotations with `@Transactional` and well you are done as that would make them parsed by Spring.